# Can’t embed any forms using a block editor in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Created a page and selected full width content from the block menu. CiviCRM button allows me to access a form selection area but once a form is selected there’s no ‘submit’ button to embed the chosen form?

Comment: Fixed your tag since it's not related to the content layout editor.  Also - if you edit your question to include CiviCRM version number you'll probably get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a wild guess here since we don't know the versions or Wordpress and CiviCRM and which block. Since you mentioned the block editor, which does not provide a CiviCRM block, I will guess that you are using a TinyMCE block that still displays a CiviCRM button -- perhaps the Classic block or Classic Paragraph block?

In my case (Wordpress 5.4.2 and CiviCRM 5.27.0), I no longer see a CiviCRM button. This is consistent with documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/. Instead, I use the Shortcode block or I directly enter a CiviCRM shortcode in a paragraph block, using the shortcode formats described in the doc.